# Name space features error in xml tags

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml as follow :

```
 <stream:features>  <readreceipts></readreceipts>  <groups_v2></groups_v2>  <privacy></privacy>  <presence></presence>  </stream:features>  
 <auth mechanism="WAUTH-2" user="919414556709">91941455670925   TnoXp8R!1449658547</auth>  
 <start from="s.whatsapp.net"></start>  
 <stream:features></stream:features>  
 <challenge>&quot;3Yw`_}.)</challenge>  
 <response>Is?F5Q:Zl[uY,!Ac</response>  
 <success t="1449658699" props="4" kind="free" status="active" creation="1449574308" expiration="1481110308">, `gy~Z5u?bK</success>  
 <presence name="SG"></presence>  
 <message to="919414556709@s.whatsapp.net" type="text" id="A0ddU1vfrD1K0" t="1449658548" notify="SG">  <body></body>  </message>  
 <ib from="s.whatsapp.net">  <offline count="0"></offline>  </ib>  
 <presence from="919414556709@s.whatsapp.net"></presence>  
 <ack from="919414556709@s.whatsapp.net" class="message" id="A0ddU1vfrD1K0" t="1449658700"></ack>  
<br />
```

I want to get all the tags I am using the code :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $res);
            foreach( $xml->xpath( '//widget') as $el) {
                $attributes = $el->attributes();
                $children = $el->children(); // OR: $el->xpath('title'); if children vary
                echo $attributes['id'] . ' ' . $children[0] . "\n";
            }
```

but getting error :

```
<b>Warning</b>:  simplexml_load_string(): namespace error : Namespace prefix stream on features is not defined in <b>C:\wampp\htdocs\Chat-API-master\examples\test.php</b> on line <b>54</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  simplexml_load_string():  &lt;stream:features&gt;  &lt;readreceipts&gt;&lt;/readreceipts&gt;  &lt;groups_v2&gt;&lt;/groups_v2&gt;  &lt;pri in <b>C:\wampp\htdocs\Chat-API-master\examples\test.php</b> on line <b>54</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  simplexml_load_string():                  ^ in <b>C:\wampp\htdocs\Chat-API-master\examples\test.php</b> on line <b>54</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in <b>C:\wampp\htdocs\Chat-API-master\examples\test.php</b> on line <b>54</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  simplexml_load_string():  &lt;auth mechanism=&quot;WAUTH-2&quot; user=&quot;919414556709&quot;&gt;91941455670925   TnoXp8R!14496585 in <b>C:\wampp\htdocs\Chat-API-master\examples\test.php</b> on line <b>54</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  simplexml_load_string():  ^ in <b>C:\wampp\htdocs\Chat-API-master\examples\test.php</b> on line <b>54</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function xpath() on boolean in <b>C:\wampp\htdocs\Chat-API-master\examples\test.php</b> on line <b>55</b><br />
```

How to resolve this error

Comment: as the error message suggests, the XML doesn't contain definition of the namespace prefix `stream`. Fix the XML, it should contains something like this : `xmlns:stream="namespace_uri_here"`

Comment: Nearly all XML tools nowadays require your XML to be namespace-well-formed (which means prefixes like "stream" must be declared). Whoever generated this namespace-ill-formed XML deserves a sharp rap over the knuckles.